# html/css text not showing

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm sure there is a question that addresses my problem but I cannot find it. I have been trying to pick up html/css and was playing around. I put together a really basic one-pager and get every thing setup but for some reason some of my text won't show. I am aware that my html and css is not the best but I cannot see why they are not visible.

The "Ultimate..." and "Learn more..." sections are what I cannot get to display.

Note: I am aware that my code is sloppy but like I said, don't see why they aren't displayed.

CSS:

```
#Ultimate
{
    width: 479px;
    height: 16px;
    font-family: 'MS Sans Serif';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
#LEARNMORE
{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 313.75px;
  top: 680.841px;
  width: 759px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 17;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id= "UltimateGame">
    ULTIMATE GAME DEVELOPMENT PLATFORM
    </div>

    <div id= "LEANRMORE">
    LEARN MORE ABOUT HOW CLOUDHUDL WORKS AND WHAT INDIE DEVELOPERS HAVE TO GAIN FROM CLOUDHUDL
    </div>
```

Comment: Could be a number of reason would have to see more ..Could be cause the font color is white and background is white?

Comment: Your `id`s in your HTML need to match the CSS.  In your case, you use `#Ultimate` in the CSS and  `id="UltimateGame"` in the HTML.  Choose one.

Comment: `680.841px;` ... really?

Comment: I suggest you check your `z-index`’s carefully ... often things hide behind each other.

Comment: ... and close the brace.

Answer (score 4):

1. LEARNMORE was spelled wrong
2. Color was white, so invisible
3. Braces were not closed

Here is a fiddle that does it right, https://jsfiddle.net/ycpoemh9/

```
 #UltimateGame
    {
        color:red;
        width: 479px;
        height: 16px;
        font-family: 'MS Sans Serif';
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    #LEARNMORE
    {
        color:blue;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
      line-height: 1.2;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      left: 313.75px;
      top: 680.841px;
      width: 759px;
      height: 35px;
      z-index: 17;
    }

     <div id= "UltimateGame" >
        ULTIMATE GAME DEVELOPMENT PLATFORM
        </div>

       <div id= "LEARNMORE">
        LEARN MORE ABOUT HOW CLOUDHUDL WORKS AND WHAT INDIE DEVELOPERS HAVE TO GAIN FROM CLOUDHUDL
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two recurrent errors in your code being that you have not closed the curly brace of your css selectors.

> CSS

```
#ultimate {
    width: 479px;
    height: 16px;
    font-family: 'MS Sans Serif';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#learn-more {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 313.75px;
  top: 680.841px;
  width: 759px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 17;
}
```

> HTML

```
<div id="ultimate">
    ULTIMATE GAME DEVELOPMENT PLATFORM
</div>

<div id="learn-more">
    LEARN MORE ABOUT HOW CLOUDHUDL WORKS AND WHAT INDIE DEVELOPERS HAVE TO GAIN FROM CLOUDHUDL
</div>
```

Although I know you have noted that your HTML is sloppy, but you should try to follow the structure that I have change your code to in the previous samples. Here are a few tips:

- Always use lowercase letters in id's and classes and separatoe different words with either a `-` or a `_`.
- Do not separate attributes, the equal sign, and their value with any spaces. (Bad: `id= "some-value"`, Good: `id="some-value"`)

Comment: Yes, I accidentally spelled it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The IDs in the HTML and CSS need to match

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are missing a bracket after the first CCS for Ultimate...rest all looks ok...after I added the bracket..it works

```
#Ultimate
{
   width: 479px;
   height: 16px;
    font-family: 'MS Sans Serif';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#LEARNMORE
{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 313.75px;
  top: 680.841px;
  width: 759px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 17;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess :

Close the brackets

```
  #Ultimate
 {
  width: 479px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: 'MS Sans Serif';
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  }
  #LEARNMORE
 {
font-size: 18px;
font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
line-height: 1.2;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
left: 313.75px;
top: 680.841px;
width: 759px;
height: 35px;
z-index: 17;
}
```

Edit : Good to see people copy pasting the same answers.If you weren't the first one to point out the mistake,you aren't that sharp.Period